# Silverlight test recorder

Tags: silverlight, automation, recorder

Is there a tool to record and play tests for a Silverlight application in both IE and firefox? 
I tried to set up Silverlight-Selenium but while setting up the Silvernium.dll file, I get the message: "The module "silvernium.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "silvernium.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FeaturePack 2 allows UI Testing for Silverlight
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269474.aspx